# Assign UITextField input to constant in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to edit an existing FitBit authentication code to learn a few things. I am really struggling to make text inserted into a text field become the assigned FitBit client ID.

Currently the client ID is set in the code, like this:

```
class AuthenticationController: NSObject, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    let clientID = "Your client ID"
```

However I want clientID to return what was inserted into my UITextField.

I have attached a full screenshot of both the loginviewcontroller and the FitBit authentication controller file.

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can make an outlet for the 
text field and use computed properties like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var clientIdTextField: UITextField!

var clientId: String? {
    return clientIdTextField.text
}
```

Property `clientId` will always return the text inside `clientIdTextField`.